# Material-Design-Lite tab tracking

Tags: google-analytics, material-design-lite

I am attempting to use material design lite to code a landing page.  I want to use tabs to separate content.  Can I track the clicks on the tabs through Google tag manager?   It seems as if all the events that fire when changing tabs are identical.

Comment: Solved with adding to the a href 
onclick= "ga('send', 'event', 'McKnights 2017 AD', 'Webinar', 'Tab Link')

Answer (score 0):

The original question specified that you wanted to use Google Tag Manager. To do this in Google Tag Manager you would just push an event onto the GTM dataLayer every time a tab is clicked. To differentiate between different tabs, you would push an extra key onto the dataLayer with the name of the tab.

An example might be:

```
dataLayer.push({'event' : 'tabSelected', 'tabName' : 'tabA'});
```

Then, in the Google Tag Manager interface, you would setup a Universal Analytics tag with track type "event" and you would pass the value of the `tabName` key to the label attribute of the GA event. The trigger of this tag would be a Custom Even trigger whose value is `tabSelected`.